# why does Google Chrome only warn about certain unencrypted connections?

Tags: google-chrome

Compare the 2 screencaps below.

Each is to a different unsecured page where a login can be performed.

Why does Chrome warn only in the first instance and not the second?

I'm assuming it is something to do with encryption... and if yes, what exactly?

Note:

1. the first screencap is from a visit to: http://test.idempiere.org/
2. the second screencap is from a visit to a PrestaShop installation on a private VPS. PrestaShop is a popular e-Commerce CMS

[image: Google Chrome warns "your connection is not private"]

[image: Google Chrome doesn't warn "your connection is not private"]

Comment: If you click the broken padlock in the omnibar it should give you more details.

Comment: is the second connection also https?

Comment: Thanks. I investigated and in layman's terms it seems that the first site is claiming a certain level of security, but cannot actually prove it... whereas the second is not claiming a level of security it can't prove.

Answer (score 0):

If you use http connections you are always prone to many attack vectors, but they are still so used that no browser warns about them yet (although, see Mozilla proposal for [deprecating unencrypted http](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/)). But you are right, those connections are definitely insecure.

However, currently HTTPS connections are checked against "known good" Certificate Authorities. If your connection does not have a trusted certificate chain, it is frowned upon.

Thankfully, these days you can get a free HTTPS validation thanks to EFF's initiative [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

First the SSL Certificate is created by PrestaShop, not by an SSL company, your os does not know the issuer of the SSL Cert. And the cert is expired. You can make a certificate at letsencrypt, if you want to make it free: https://letsencrypt.org/.
[That was my browser say(in german)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfqHs.png)